# How do I best turn on an intro in front of my app?

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner and would like to put an intro in front of my app. so far this is difficult because I already have a lot of screens. Maybe you have a tip how to solve this best?

https://snack.expo.io/@knefie/application-neu

Do you have any other suggestions for improvement?
I wanted to outsource the header and footer. But that was not possible with my previous knowledge.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using expo try to use the AppLoading Component together with SplashScreen.
Here is an article from expo maybe it helps you : https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/guides/splash-screens/